# Slow loading react-native-vector-icons in react native build app

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have an Intro screen that is lunched when user open app and wait a second too loads some data from local DB. In this screen I show an icon from react-native-vector-icon/FontAwesome. It is loading with no delay in metro but when I build my app and install it on my phone it takes one or two seconds to load.

I added this line in my build.gradle file in android/app folder:
`apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")`

And also I get this warning but I don't know it is related to this Issue or not:
*Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.*

react-native-vector-icons version: 10.0.0
react-native version: 0.72.4